# How to improve the execute efficiency of this sql?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

The sql throws timeout exception in the PRD environment.

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(*) totalCount,
    SUM(IF(t.RESULT_FLAG = 'success', 1, 0)) successCount,
    SUM(IF(b.ERROR_CODE = 'Y140', 1, 0)) unrecognizedCount,
    SUM(IF(b.ERROR_CODE LIKE 'Y%' OR b.ERROR_CODE = 'E008', 1, 0)) connectCall,
    SUM(IF(b.ERROR_CODE = 'N004', 1, 0)) hangupUnconnect,
    SUM(IF(b.ERROR_CODE = 'Y001', 1, 0)) hangupConnect
FROM
    lbl_his b LEFT JOIN lbl_error_code t ON b.TASK_ID = t.TASK_ID AND t.CODE = b.ERROR_CODE
WHERE
     b.TASK_ID = "5f460e4ffa99f51697ad4ae3"
AND b.CREATE_TIME BETWEEN "2020-07-01 00:00:00" AND "2020-10-28 00:00:00"
```

The size of table lbl_his is super large. About 20,000,000 rows data which occupied 20GB disk.

The size of table lbl_error_code is small. Only 305 rows.

The indexes of table lbl_his:

```
TASK_ID
UPDATE_TIME
CREATE_TIME
RECORD_ID
```

The union indexes of table lbl_his:

```
TASK_ID, ERROR_CODE, UPDATE_TIME
TASK_ID, CREATE_TIME
```

There are no index created for table lbl_error_code.
I ran `EXPLAIN SELECT` and found the sql hit the index of lbl_his.TASK_ID and lbl_error_code.primary.

How to avoid to execute timeout?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL? I *assume* MySQL as `IF` isn't a function in T-SQL. Also, those are odd choices for aliases; "b" is for "his" and "t" is for "error_code"?

Comment: Create index on `lbl_his (TASK_ID, ERROR_CODE, CREATE_TIME)`. What is approximate rows amount where `lbl_his.TASK_ID = "5f460e4ffa99f51697ad4ae3"`?

Comment: Right, I'm using MySQL. That's because I rename the table and forgot to rename the aliases, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

For an index solution on `lbl_his`, try putting a non-clustered index on

- firstly the things you filter on by exact match
- then the things you filter on as ranges (or inexact matches)

e.g., the initial part of the index should be `TASK_ID` then `CREATE_TIME`. Putting these first is very important as it means the engine can do one seek to get the data.

Then include any other fields in use (either as part of index, or includes - doesn't matter) - in this case,  `ERROR_CODE`. This makes your index a covering index.

Therefore your final new non-clustered index on `lbl_his` should be `(TASK_ID, CREATE_TIME, ERROR_CODE)`